# Grails 3 project getting 'Cannot resolve symbol in IntelliJ IDEA' for various files

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, grails3

I am using Grails 3.3.8 with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.1, but the view editor doesn't show it correctly for some reason even though I have all the configuration and dependencies. The same error/warning comes in gsp's as well. Also I am using the shiro-plugin and get the error's for its tags saying that it's not allowed.

No issue is faced while running the app but not sure why the code is not detected by IntelliJ correctly. I also tried Refresh All Gradle projects many times and even did a grails clean and build but they still show.

**Note:** I have the same project running on Grails 2.5.6 and it detects all fine in the same IDE version. This is when I upgraded the project to 3.3.8.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't know that `tablePerHierarchy` is valid in that context.  

If you are requesting this is a feature enhancement to IntelliJ, you should send it to their issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks sure will do.

Comment: @HasanK Please check with 2018.3.2 release and if the issues persist, report them at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.